# [Suggestion]: New user start from non-zero reputation points?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, reputation, new-users

Let's be honest, this site is challenging for a new user to work with. Our new users are struggling. But why are they struggling? Many our new users are more than technically capable of answering programming questions, but they aren't doing it. Why?

I think the main reason is that we are forcing a new user to start from zero reputation point. Starting from scratch is not what we do in programming. So we should offer a new scheme that them start from non-zero points.

What about we allow them to start from **10k points** in the first month of probation? The points would slowly decay to zero if the system detected no useful engagement. They will have a month to prove to us.

It's not a new idea. In World Of Warcraft, a [new Death Knight](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Hero_class) hero start from level 55 and people like it this way. I think we will receive a great boost in new user engagement if we give them a chance to thrive. Hero class on Stackoverflow? (similar idea but we will need to change the name)

Comment: "What about we allow them to start from 10k points in the first month of probation?" - because this opens for so much abuse it would be easier to shut the entire site down than managing it. Unlocking instant review, upvote, downvote, deletion, and edit privileges is a _horrible_ idea from an abuse perspective

Comment: I don’t think starting everyone off with almost all moderation tools and privileges unlocked is a good idea. The amount of damage spam bots could do with full editing privileges alone would be devastating. Then there’s that moderation rules aren’t obvious to new users so you’ll have a bunch of people doing that wrong even if they mean well. We have experienced users doing Triage wrong now, it’ll be worse if everyone has access to everything.

Comment: The site is challenging for a new user to work with because our on-boarding system sucks.

Comment: But to be fair, for new users it is a little bit like walking into a foreign country where the rules make no sense.  I'll give just two examples: 1. high-reputation, wildly popular questions that get a lot of visibility, but don't contribute to the wiki ethos.  Hell, we even *protect* them, *lock* them as historical artifacts, and put them on the the Hot Network Questions list so they get even more visibility.  You can hardly blame new users for thinking it's OK to ask questions like this.

Comment: I think users with 1 to 9000 rep will like that. Or they will delete their account to create a new one.

Comment: 2.  Setting as one of your goals the gathering and curation of a repository of useful programming knowledge, while at the same time catering to popularity by allowing the asking of code troubleshooting twenty-questions style posts; posts for which the available site tools are roundly unsuitable.

Comment: Giving people free internet points will not fix either of those problems.

Comment: SO is not about reputation and earning points. This is only the side effect of providing good content and contributing positively to the site. Sorry but your comparaison with WOW doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also, while we're at it, imagine if spammers were given the edit privilege the second they joined the site, guaranteed. Various API fuckery could enable several edits per second on an unrestricted 10k account.

Comment: TBF.... lore-wise DKs start at levels 55 because they're reborn heroes. It would be more useful to think about that as experienced users being brought back from suspensions at a high rep level because they've already earned it.... which already happens. And in the coming expansion, guess what, they'll start at level 1 (or maybe 10?) :p

Comment: This is not a duplicate because this question is proposing giving more privleges to new users, whereas the target is proposing articifially increasing the reputation numbers (without giving anyone more rights) to make being downvoted feel bad.

Comment: ok, as new member and thus directly appointed moderator with 120k rep, I undeleted & reopened the question. I know i have posted an answer, and maybe I should let others do the job, but I'm pretty tired of people closing with wrong duplicates & then deleting meta posts just because the question has negative score.

Comment: "Many our new users are more than technically capable of answering programming questions, but they aren't doing it. Why?" Note that "answering programming questions" doesn't require any particular rep level. So there's nothing stopping folks doing that right from the start. There *is* something stopping them taking moderator actions, and that's only right and proper.

Comment: What is the requirement for having a Level 55 DK in WOW? For 6 year in order to have a level 55, you had to have one level 55+ on any server. On new realms DK, for fresh, was not allowed before char transfers on new account. On SO you are level 33, and asking for level 55 + power. SO it's not Chess.SE, like RP-PVE are not Vanilla-PVP. And the restriction went away because they add level 90 for 50$ boost. So when the restriction went away in 2014 no Fresh account was interested in DK. Blizz shared stats about this.

Comment: Create  a 10K account, donate 70% to every questions you can find via bounty, Get involved with one for the bounty in order to get around ~100 rep. Repeat. With a 1% redistriduction of the 10K, users win more that other upvote ring method in less time. All the bounty except one or two are legitimate. So reputation roll back become harder. In less than a week everyone is Jon Skeet.

Comment: 1. Give every new user 10k rep at the start. 2. Give every existing user +9999 rep. 3. Shift all privileges adding 9999 rep to the requirement to get them. Done!

Comment: _Starting from scratch is not what we do in programming._ Sometimes I'd love starting a program from scratch...

Comment: Shouldn’t this be marked status-completed? New users start at one (a non-zero amount) of rep.

Answer (score 26):

Good news: This feature already exists for users having a given reputation on other stack exchange sites (known as *association bonus*).

In that case, the user starts at 101 points, so can upvote, comment, and will be able to downvote in a few.

The system considers that if you were able to have a positive contribution on any site of the network, you're trustworthy enough to be granted 100 free points so the experience on this new site won't be as frustrating as for the first one. But we can't let random people (or bots) have reputation (and certainly not 10000!!) without any guarantee.

Yes, first steps on StackOverflow can be harsh, but that's also because of the fact that this site is used by a lot of people who seek help because they're in the computer business for a living, but aren't particularly fond of the subject.

But it's different a lot of stackexchange sites (except maybe for SuperUser), where even new people ask better questions because 1) they already know the subject and 2) their jobs/degree aren't at stake (from my experience for instance at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/). People aren't so desperate in getting an answer urgently.

Granting 10k points to any starting user would allow anyone to create accounts, edit/downvote/upvote at will, create another account, repeat... Account suspended? Rep dropped to 1? not a problem, getting 10k with another account. We have enough issues with question ban evasion accounts already.

Not to mention users below 10k would create a new account just to get the 10k.

With that 10k-at-account-creation feature implemented, the site would become a wasteland in no time.